# How to check for record by using ID, then if record exists update if not add new record

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I've create an excel userform to collect data. I have connected it to Access to dump the data. However I want to update Access every time a user presses the submit button.

Basically I need the Select statement to determine an id existence, then if it doesn't exists I need to use the INSERT to add the new row. I'm very new with any SQL so any help would be great.

Here is the code I have now, I need to adapt it to ADO.

```
Sub Update()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyConn
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim StrSql As String

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open MyConn

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.Open Source:="Foam", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
        CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
        Options:=adCmdTable





StrSql = "SELECT * FROM Foam WHERE FoamID = " & txtMyID
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSql, dbOpenDynaset)

If (rst.RecordCount = 0) Then
     DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Foam (ID, Part, Job, Emp, Weight, Oven) VALUES " & _
          "(" & txtID & ", '" & txtField1 & "', '" & txtField2 & "', '" & txtField3 & "', '" & txtField4 & "', '" & txtField5 & "' );"

End If

 ' Close the connection
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing


End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I revised your code sample just enough to get it working on my system and tested this version in Excel 2007.

When I use a value for `lngId` which matches the `id` of an existing record, that record is opened in the recordset and I can update the values of its fields.

When `lngId` does not match the `id` of an existing record, the recordset opens empty [`(.BOF And .EOF) = True`].  In that situation, I add a new record and add the field values to it.

```vb
Sub Update()
    Const TARGET_DB As String = "database1.mdb"
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim MyConn As String
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim StrSql As String
    Dim lngId As Long

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB
    With cnn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Open MyConn
    End With

    lngId = 4
    StrSql = "SELECT * FROM tblFoo WHERE id = " & lngId
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rst
        .CursorLocation = adUseServer
        .Open Source:=StrSql, ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
                CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
                Options:=adCmdText
        If (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            ' no match found; add new record
            .AddNew
            !ID = lngId
            !some_text = "Hello World"
        Else
            ' matching record found; update it
            !some_text = "Hello World"
        End If
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    Set rst = Nothing
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Would there need to be significant changes for excel 2013? I get "error 3265 Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." The !some+text = "Hello World" trips this error

Comment: `some_text` is the name of a field in my `tblFoo` table.  Substitute your field name.  If that name includes space, punctuation, or any characters other than letters, digits, or `_`, enclose the field name in square brackets like this ... `![your field]`

Comment: Thank you SO much! I've actually updated my access DB from an excel userform! Now I just need to populate the updates to the DB from the text fields and not static values. But you've got me very close! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA, here is a sample of how to query for a certain `ID` to check if it exists.  If it does not then add it via an `INSERT` statement:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSql As String

StrSql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = " & txtMyID
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSql, dbOpenDynaset)

If (rs.RecordCount = 0) Then
  DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Field1, Field2) VALUES " & _
           "(" & txtID & ", '" & txtField1 & "', '" & txtField2 & "');"
End If
```

Comment: How can I change the 101, Whatever, Man) into the newly added data?

Comment: **@user3297842**, I updated my answer to address your first comment.

Comment: for some reason it has a problem with this line. Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSql, dbOpenDynaset)

Comment: is Currentdb the problem, is that something I need to personalize?

Comment: It's telling me object required and giving me a 424 error

Comment: Actually, since i'm not using DAO I'm using ADODB, I cannot use DAO.RecordSet so I need a similar command to CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSql, dbOpenDynaset) but using ADODB

Comment: I posted my code, I'd prefer to adapt it to ADO, since all my other code is in ADO and I'll get lost easily. In the mean time I'll try your suggestions, and set the DAO reference and lingers code

Comment: actually, the SAME recordset can be used, and a .addnew. No need to execute a brand new SQL insert statement