# RecordSet Filtering not detecting duplicates or modifying existing rows

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

After spending many hours trying to fix this issue, I'm not sure how to proceed.  I'm trying to add data from a spreadsheet to an Access table but I don't want any duplicates in the table and I want updated versions of existing rows to replace the existing rows.  I feel I've exhausted what's on the internet pertaining to this issue.  I used the thread from the following Stack Overflow link ([How to check for record by using ID, then if record exists update if not add new record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706069/how-to-check-for-record-by-using-id-then-if-record-exists-update-if-not-add-new)) to help me out a lot but my interpretation of the code isn't doing what I need it to do.  I get no syntax errors; but my SQL statement, which is supposed to filter the recordset by determining if the spreadsheet data matches any current database entries, is returning an empty recordset when there are at least five exact duplicates of each spreadsheet entry in the database table.  I'm totally stuck as to what is the issue.  Below is my code:

```
Public Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
    'Variable definition
    InputDate = Tracking.Sheets("P&Q Weekly Summary").Range("E3").Value
    Call SetDataConnection
    Set DataRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    With DataRecordset
        For DataRowCount = 2 To TrackingLastRow
            Part_Number = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("A" & DataRowCount).Value
            Week_Day = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("B" & DataRowCount).Value
            Weekday_Name = WeekdayName(Weekday(Week_Day))
            Quantity = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("C" & DataRowCount).Value
            Machine = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("G" & DataRowCount).Value
            'Attempting to find duplicate entry
            SQLCmd = "SELECT * FROM Raw_Data WHERE [Part] = '" & Part_Number & "' AND [Day] = " & Week_Day & " AND [Quantity] = " & Quantity & " AND [Machine] = '" & Machine & "';"
            .Open Source:=SQLCmd, ActiveConnection:=DBConnection, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdText
            If (.BOF) Or (.EOF) Then
                MsgBox .RecordCount
                'No match found; add new record
                .AddNew
                .Fields("Part") = Part_Number
                .Fields("Week") = InputDate
                .Fields("Day") = Week_Day
                .Fields("Weekday") = Weekday_Name
                .Fields("Quantity") = Quantity
                .Fields("Adjusted Quantity") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("D" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Sample") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("E" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Rejected") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("F" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Machine") = Machine
                .Fields("Cycle") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("H" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Operator") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("I" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Update
                DataRowCount = DataRowCount + 1
            'If current line already exists in database
            Else
                .Fields("Part") = Part_Number
                .Fields("Week") = InputDate
                .Fields("Day") = Week_Day
                .Fields("Weekday") = Weekday_Name
                .Fields("Quantity") = Quantity
                .Fields("Adjusted Quantity") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("D" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Sample") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("E" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Rejected") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("F" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Machine") = Machine
                .Fields("Cycle") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("H" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Fields("Operator") = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("I" & DataRowCount).Value
                .Update
                DataRowCount = DataRowCount + 1
            End If
            .Close
        Next DataRowCount
    End With
    Set DataRecordset = Nothing
    DBConnection.Close
    Set DBConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you for the help.  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'd try removing the criteria from the WHERE clause then add them back one at a time and see at which point you lose all the records. Then at least you can double check the data for that field.

Comment: As per Rory's answer, except I usually use debugging to get the SQLCmd value, and put it in a new query in SQL view, then switch back to design view. As Rory said, remove each criteria until you find the issue. Often you'll spot the prob whilst in design view.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, it helped a lot.  All fields and combinations did not produce duplicates except when WHERE [Day] = " & Week_Day & " was used.  This is my problem criteria.  In Access, the [Day] column is in the General Date format.  The corresponding column in the Excel spreadsheet is in the Date format too.  Somehow these two columns must not be recognizing each other's corresponding formats I'm guessing.  Any ideas on what specifically could be going wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my SQL statement was the date criterion.  Apparently, special syntax is required for date and time criteria per MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627355(v=office.12).aspx#Access2007BuildingSQLStatements_UsingDateTimeCriteria).  Instead of the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE [Day] = " & Week_Day & "
```

The following code reflects the changes, particularly the requisite #'s:

```
WHERE [Day] = #" & Week_Day & "#
```

The above link demonstrates this fairly clearly.  I would not have discovered this without parsing through my WHERE statements on by one.  All the others were fine except for the one with the date criterion.  Problem solved.